# How do I encode location data for linear regression in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression

I am doing a beginner project to predict house prices. I have one category called 'city' with values such as Boston, Detroit, NY, etc.

If I use One Hot Encoder I will end up with a very huge dataset because there are around 100 unique values. But I am unsure about using Label Encoding because the regression may treat the values as numerical.

I thought that would be plenty explained on the internet as it is a typical exercise but I am unable to find a solution. How do I encode location data?

Comment: Label encoding should be avoided in your use case since your categorical variable is naturally unordered. The reason behind that is ML algorithms might misjudge numeric values as having some order in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a categorical feature with many unique values, try using [target encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-categorical-variables-by-using-target-encoder-a0f1733a4c69)

The idea is to calculate average price for each city and then replace city name with that average for each row. This average price will tell your model how attractive this city in general.

One possible implementation is this:

```py
mean_by_city = df.groupby("city").agg({"price": "mean"}).squeeze().to_dict()
df["city_mean_encoding"] = df["city"].map(mean_by_city)
```

One advice: don't forget to check for rare categories. If your dataset has only few examples of houses in some small town, the mean might not be accurate. In this case I can recommend to add a dummy "Rare" category.

Comment: Thank you. That set me on the right track. Investigating I found out about 'smoothing' too. Is there a rule of thumb for considering a category rare? Like <30 or less than a certain percentage of n?

Comment: From my experience, 100 is a good threshold, but it depends. I can also recommend making a bar chart of mean_by_city and checking if it looks good (smooth, no outliers, ...)

Answer (score 0):

When someone wants to encode categories (e.g. "apple", "pineapple"). Then you can set the task as: "Encode categorial features". For this task we have a huge number of solutions.
Suppose we have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['cat'] = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Nissan']
data
```

Output:

```
    cat
0   BMW
1   Mercedes
2   Nissan
```

Let's use BinaryEncoder. This encoder uses less space than One Hot Encoder.

```
from category_encoders.binary import BinaryEncoder
bn = BinaryEncoder()
bn.fit_transform(data.values)
```

Output:

```
  0_0 0_1
0   0   1
1   1   0
2   1   1
```

If you want to use more advanced solutions, take a look at this [framework](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/).

Edit:

```
But I am unsure about using Label Encoding because the regression may treat the values as numerical.
```

It's okay to use Label Encoding for linear regression. Because linear regression "know" difference only between exogenous variables and endogenous variables. And don't "know" difference between categorial and non categorial features. You must use numerical represantation of categorial features. But Label Encoding have a big problem. This method add linear dependence between categorials. Example:

```
"first", "second" --> "1", "2"
```

But "first" not bigger than "second". So we can get wrong results from linear regression.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely learned from your answer. If I am correct Label Encoding would treat the values as ordinal when they should not.